# systemverilog always_comb construct does not infer purely

Tags: system-verilog

```
import rv32i_types::*;

module cmp
(
    input [2:0] sel,
    input [31:0] a, b,
    output logic f
);

always_comb
begin
    case (sel)
        beq:  
              if(a==b)
                    out = 1'b1;
                else
                    out = 1'b0;

        bne: 
                if(a!=b)
                    out = 1'b1;
                else
                    out = 1'b0;
        blt:
              if($signed(a) < $signed(b))
                  out = 1'b1;
                else
                    out = 1'b0;

        bge:
              if($signed(a) > $signed(b))
                  out = 1'b1;
                else
                    out = 1'b0;

        bltu:
              if(a < b)
                    out = 1'b1;
                else
                    out = 1'b0;

        bgeu:
              if(a > b)
                    out = 1'b1;
                else
                    out = 1'b0;
    endcase
end

endmodule : cmp
```

Whenever I run this, it says always_comb construct does not infer purely combinational logic
What is the issue?

Answer (score 4):

The error means there is some storage inferred by your code. Since `sel` is 3 bits, there are 8 possible values and your `case` statement only has 6. Then you don’t have an assignment to out in all possible flows through your block. You need to provide a `default` branch or make an assignment before the `case` statement.